# How to freeze one or more columns in MS ReportViewer control?

Tags: reportviewer

Is it possible to "freeze" a column in Microsoft ReportViewer control local mode so that as the user scrolls to the right the first column or two continues to show and doesn't scroll out of view?  I am using table type of report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution.

You have to click on the column above the header of the report designer.  It will select whole column including Table Header, Table Details, Table Footer and click on the property (F4).  Change FixedHeader Property to True.