# Is possible to freeze the reportviewer column's header?

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I'm using `ReportViewer` and I'd like to know if it's possible to set the Column's Header as `Fixed` ?
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2298109/1919644) topic but the answer didn't work out the way I need.
I need to freeze the `column's header` so when the user scroll the `reportviewer` down, the `column's headers` will always be visible...

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that is possible in the ReportViewer control.

Since the report ultimately outputs to HTML in the ReportViewer, you are bound to the natural capabilities of a webpage.  The functionality would be similar to Facebook's header bar, where it stays locked at the top as you scroll down your newsfeed.  That is implemented using JavaScript, and it would be difficult to find an appropriate mechanism and have it work correctly with the ReportViewer's outputted HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean "keep header visible while scrolling"?
There is an option for it in the designer,

Right click table/tablix -> Properties -> General Tab -> Under Column Headers -> Keep header visible while scrolling.

**EDIT:**

Realize that the Report, once loaded is just HTML. So if you wanted to achieve your goal through CSS (and maybe a little bit of javascript) this is always an option.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work out... When I scroll down the `content of the reportviewer` the `column's header` still going up and not visible =\
I guess it's not possible

Comment: Have you tried in Internet Explorer? I know quite a few features of ReportViewer only work in IE. I personally have not tried it myself but it should work. "Should" :/