# .rdlc Report freeze first column with a Row Group

Tags: c#, rdlc, rowheader

i am really frustrated because I tried and googled several hours for this simple problem. I hope someone can help me here.

I want to freeze the first column of my tablix located on my .rdlc report.
I have tried both posibilites described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220509.aspx)
but only the column headers get freezed, the row headers (first column in my understanding) don't stay visible while I scroll to right...

Maybe I do something essencial wrong and don't see it, please help me with this little, frustrating thing...

I wanted to upload a Screenshot of my tablix at design time but the upload tool returns a error...maybe it works later when there is a need for it.

Edit: Here is the uploaded [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/cp64f51mv)

Best Regards

Alexander

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297802/how-to-freeze-one-or-more-columns-in-ms-reportviewer-control

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my tablix has no FixedHeader property when I select the first column.